# send bulk sms from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, sms

I've been trying to use the code below to send sms but it does not send when I loop.  It only works if I just pick one number from database. I have over 5,000 numbers in the database and wish to send an sms to all of them at the same time, Please help.

```
mysql_select_db($database_xxx, $xxx);
$query_rs = "SELECT phone FROM `notify` order by id asc LIMIT $l1 , $l2";
$rs= mysql_query($query_rs, $xxx) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rs = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);
$totalRows_rs= mysql_num_rows($rs);

$phone = $row_rs['phone'];

// Do while loop to send sms.
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)){


                         // Let's do some formatting and keep smiling.
    $giringirin = ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $phone );
    if (strlen($giringirin) == 11) { 
    $phone1=substr($giringirin, 1);
    $phone= "234$phone1";
    } elseif (strlen($giringirin) == 13){ 
    $phone = $giringirin; 
    }

extract($_POST);


//set POST variables
$url = "http://sms.xxx.com/bulksms/bulksms.php?username=$username&password=$password&message=$smsmessage&mobile=$phone&sender=$sender";
$fields = array(
        );

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string,'&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

if ($result == '1801') { echo "SMS has also been sent to the Customer ($phone) \n";} else { echo "Oooops, No sms was sent";}

//close connection
curl_close($ch);  
}
```

Comment: no need to hide the sms provider name, the answer may well be specific to their api

Answer (score 0):

Your code is confusing...

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
```

CURLOPT_POST is a boolean flag. Either you're doing a post, or you're not. The number of fields you're posting is irrelevant.

You're building up a series of variables/values to be posted, but doing it via string operations. CURL is perfectly capable of taking an array and doing all that for you, reducing your entire foreach loop to just

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
```

You're using `extract()` on `$_POST`, which pollutes your script's variable namespace with any garbage a malicious user cares to send over - you're essentially replicating PHP's utterly moronically brain-dead `register_globals` all over again.

You're using `ereg`, which has been deprecated for approximiately 5 million internet years. You should be using the `preg` functions insteadl

Answer (score -1):

What happens when you run this script in the browser? Blank page? Something? Error?

Start by changing

```
$url = "http://sms.xxx.com/bulksms/bulksms.php?username=$username&password=$password&message=$smsmessage&mobile=$phone&sender=$sender";
```

to

```
$url = "http://sms.xxx.com/bulksms/bulksms.php?username=".$username."&password=".$password."&message=".$smsmessage."&mobile=".$phone."&sender=".$sender."";
```

Comment: -1. That does nothing. You're simply changing some visuals in the script. `$x = "a$b"` is functionally identical to `$x = 'a' . $b;`.

Comment: in a double-quoted string variable names are expanded

Comment: hm? ah, well yes. But it is good practice nonetheless; single quotes would have caused a problem